# How to compile with unsafe when running in Azure Websites

Tags: c#, azure, unsafe

I have a `C#` `MVC` site hosted on `Azure Websites`, and I need to include a:

```
unsafe {
  fixed (float* f = myFloatArray) {

  }
}
```

block of code. This works great on my development machine locally (when running through the debugger). I have - of course - enabled the `Allows unsafe code` checkbox in my project settings.

My issue is that when I **Publish** the project to Azure Websites using the right-click-project-Publish approach, the build tells me I need to compile with `/unsafe` (which is what I thought I was doing by checking the `Allow unsafe code` checkbox in my project settings).

How can I get my `unsafe` code to publish to `Azure Websites`? What could I be doing incorrectly here?

Comment: When you publish, it may be compiling against the `Release` build, rather than `Debug`.  Are you sure you set the `Allows unsafe code` for the `Release` build as well?

Comment: I would fully expect Azure to not allow the use of any projects containing unsafe code.  It's important for you to not have complete control over the machine the code is executing on when using cloud computing, and those restrictions aren't possible when enabling unsafe code.  Finding a way to deploy unsafe code is almost certainly a security vulnerability, if you find a way.

Comment: @NathanA Ah wow, I missed that. So simple, and explains everything :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you publish, it may be compiling against the `Release` build, rather than `Debug`.

Make sure you set the `Allows unsafe code` for the `Release` build as well.

Comment: `unsafe` code requires full trust, and when publishing code that's going to run on a cloud you're basically never going to have that.

Comment: @Servy Azure allows this anyways. I'm not sure when they changed it, but my code executes now (correctly), so at least the `unsafe` keyword is allowed.

Comment: @Servy that's most likely true, but the answer to the Op's particular problem is that the flag wasn't set on Release, not because of an Azure restriction.

Comment: With Azure Functions, you can publish with unsafe code, as long as it is allowed for Release