# compiling with unsave for azure functions c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions

When im trying to publish my code to Azure functions i get this error message

```
 error CS0227: Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe
```

I already enabled unsafe mode on properties->Build -> check Allow unsafe code.

I have not found anything to publish unsafe mode on azure function, is this even posible? or is it some configuration under azure?

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24615679/4122889

Comment: Same question, thanks. but how to Allows unsafe code for the Release?