# How to allow unsafe code for Release and Debug on visual studio 2019 .net5.0

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, unsafe

I viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615618/how-to-compile-with-unsafe-when-running-in-azure-websites/24615679#24615679) asking how to allow unsafe code for azure functions publish code.

This suggest to `"Make sure you set the Allows unsafe code for the Release build as well."`

I already enabled unsafe mode on *Project Properties -> Build -> Check Allow unsafe code*.

But I don't find the difference between enable unsafe code on *Debug* and *Release*.

Im using Visual Studio 2019 .Net 5.0

Where is the path to enable it on Release?

Comment: Did you change the build mode selection to "Release" via the top combo box? What's the "*difference*" that you can't find? What compared to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on your project file then apply the following image. Configuration menu should have Release mode too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No matter what IDE you use, you can just activate that by adding a property group to your csproj file like done in this example for both `Release` and `Debug`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
    </Project>
```